# I am trying to create trip schedule with custom fields using Woocommerce Booking Availibility

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display my custom fields (Destinations, Availibility, etc) into my Booking availibility page. I am using Woocommerce Bookings & Woo Bookings Availibility but in the vanilla version of Availibility plugin there is no option to display my custom fields.

This is the display I am trying to achieve: https://www.dive-damai.com/schedule

And this is how my current schedule looks like using the Woocommerce Booking Availibility plugin:
[image: My schedule]

I have tried adding this code to the plugin's base code (woocommerce-bookings-availability.php) but then the site went critical error:

```
/**
 * Registers the blocks.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function register_blocks() {
    if (!class_exists('WC_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    register_block_type(
        'woocommerce/bookings-availability-calendar-block',
        array(
            'script' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-calendar-block-frontend',
            'editor_script' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-calendar-block',
            'style' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-calendar-block-style-frontend',
            'editor_style' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-calendar-block-style',
            'render_callback' => array($this, 'render_calendar_block'),
        )
    );

    register_block_type(
        'woocommerce/bookings-availability-schedule-block',
        array(
            'script' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-schedule-block-frontend',
            'editor_script' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-schedule-block',
            'style' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-schedule-block-style-frontend',
            'editor_style' => 'woocommerce-bookings-availability-schedule-block-style',
            'render_callback' => array($this, 'render_schedule_block'),
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Render callback for the calendar block.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param array $attributes Block attributes.
 * @param string $content Block content.
 * @return string Rendered block HTML.
 */
public function render_calendar_block($attributes, $content)
{
    ob_start();
    echo $content;

    // Get the custom field values
    $destination = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'destination', true);
    $date_from = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_from', true);
    $date_to = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_to', true);
    $trip_duration = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'trip_duration', true);

    // Display the custom field values
    echo '<p>Destination: ' . $destination . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Date From: ' . $date_from . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Date To: ' . $date_to . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Trip Duration: ' . $trip_duration . '</p>';

    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Render callback for the schedule block.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param array $attributes Block attributes.
 * @param string $content Block content.
 * @return string Rendered block HTML.
 */
public function render_schedule_block($attributes, $content)
{
    ob_start();
    echo $content;

    // Get the custom field values
    $destination = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'destination', true);
    $date_from = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_from', true);
    $date_to = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_to', true);
    $trip_duration = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'trip_duration', true);

    // Display the custom field values
    echo '<p>Destination: ' . $destination . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Date From: ' . $date_from . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Date To: ' . $date_to . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Trip Duration: ' . $trip_duration . '</p>';

    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

I tried to activate WP-Debug then this error shows up:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting
> "function" or "const" in
> G:\PleskVhosts\liveaboard.dune-world.com\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce-bookings-availability\woocommerce-bookings-availability.php
> on line 277
>
> Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query
> tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always
> return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
> (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in
> G:\PleskVhosts\liveaboard.dune-world.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php
> on line 5827
>
> Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query
> tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always
> return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
> (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in
> G:\PleskVhosts\liveaboard.dune-world.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php
> on line 5827

Would you guys please help me solve this? I have been stuck in this for like a week :') thanks!

Comment: The error messages refer to functions not shown ( or their invocations - `is_search` and `is_embed` ) and we have no idea which is line 277. Please add sufficient details to clarify these things